# Is there any service that can send requests to a URL from a specified city?

Tags: geolocation

Basically I'm trying to test a feature of my website, which displays the location(city-level) you're at when visiting my site. And the testing approach I'm planning is: using a host in an arbitrary city to send requests to my site, with the city name appended to the URL, and then compare the known city name with the city name calculated by my site.

This approach requires a service that, given an arbitrary city name and a URL, it asks a host in that city to send requests to that URL.

Does such service/tool/library actually exist? Or is there a better testing approach for that feature?

Answer (score 0):

I frequently do outside-my-network proxies via [ProxySwitchy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caehdcpeofiiigpdhbabniblemipncjj), which is a plugin in Chrome.

Simply install in your browser, get a proxy from [the many lists out there](http://www.xroxy.com/), test quickly on a known website to ensure the proxy is working (ESPN or Google is fine--proxies frequently go up and down, so you want to make sure they're working before you test!) then navigate to your test site.  You can setup several test proxies in ProxySwitchy and just toggle the list by clicking on the "world" icon in the upper right corner.

A [page like this](http://www.hostip.info/) could show you what you should expect to see.

It also works great for testing domain change propagation, path interruptions, and more.  Just don't abuse it!